# Create autosuggest textbox with ajax

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to create autosuggest textbox with ajax. After writing some character it will return email address. Starting with those characters from DB. That should be developed in JSP. Can anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do as following:

in javascript:

```
function getValue(str){
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
url = url +"?" +str;
 xmlhttp.open("POST",url_to_get_db_data,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById('id_of_div').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById('id_of_div').style.display = "block";
}
```

and in html:

```
<input onkeypress="getValue(this.value)"/>   //--- this will be your input text
<div id="id_of_div" style="display:none;">   //--- this is your autosuggest box which will appear down to textbox. Use css to show it at proper location.
</div>
```

format your div to look like a autosuggest box. use `css` to achieve this.

Also when user selects one option from autosuggest box call java script function which does following
 `document.getElementById('id_of_div').style.display = "none";`

**Edit**

at server side when you get database list do as follows:

```
for(Iterator it=db_list.iterator();it.hasNext();)
    {
        Object obj = (Object) it.next();
        String value = obj.getValue();
        out.print(value+"<br>");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mayur: i've edited my question for more understanding. take a look

Comment: Thanks Harry....in that url what should be the logic for comparing each character in DB through 'like%' and at the last i will get a list of those ...do we hv to set that list smwhere??                can u explain me in that way???....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) shipped with jQuery UI.

Have a look their [official demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which illustrates how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at integrating jquery UI with your web application. The jquery UI has the autocomplete/suggestion plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

It is ajax and all you need to do is just supply a list of words

Comment: Hi...I'm using this http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete link only...but facing problem in that page which is calling from that function...do i hv to return anything from the page..in which i'm getting all data..???